# Yii2 using ArrayHelper with another database

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `Yii2`. I am using `mysql` and `mssql` databases. The `mssql` is on a remote site and I am able to access it. Now I am trying to add a dropdown list.

**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new AllowArea();
    $sds = Yii::$app->sds->createCommand("Select * from Area")->queryAll();// mssql Database

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'sds' => $sds
    ]);
}
```

**View**

`<?= $form->field($model, 'salesman_code')->dropDownList(\common\models\AllowArea::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => 'Select a Booker']) ?>`

**Model**

In my model, I have a function

```
public static function toArrayList(){
    $sds = Yii::$app->sds->createCommand("Select * from Salesmen")->queryAll();


    return ArrayHelper::map($sds::find()->all(),'SalesmanCode',function($sds, $defaultValue){
        return $sds['SalesmanCode'].' - '.$sds['SalesmanNameFull'];
    });
}
```

Previously I was using `self` in place of `$sds`. With `$sds` I am getting error

> Class name must be a valid object or a string

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You don't need `::find()->all`, because your variable `$sds` must return array with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `Model/Class`. So, in ArrayHelper

```
return ArrayHelper::map($sds, 'SalesmanCode', function($sds) {
    return $sds['SalesmanCode'].' - '.$sds['SalesmanNameFull'];
});
```